# Scenarios that demonstrate use of delegates vs non-use

Tags: c#, delegates

I've seen many instances of code samples that show the benefits of using delegates.  However, the purpose of using delegates would be made more clear if a delegate-based code sample can be compared with  code that models the same process, but without a delegate.  This would also showcase the consequential problems of writing code that should use delegates, but is not.

Would be great if someone could paste such samples here..

EDIT:  I am not asking for opinions.  I am asking for specific example(s) that demonstrate two different solutions to the same problem.  Where one solution uses delegates and the other does not.

Comment: It's not an all-in situation. Sometimes delegates fit the job, sometimes they don't. If you know when you would use them, you should be able to come up with a matching "anti-pattern" yourself. In any case: Responses and answers will be highly opinion based.

Comment: And I did't ask for an "all-in".  I didn't ask for opinions either.  I asked for specific scenarios.  This question doesn't warrant an arrest by SO Gestapo..who apparently have nothing better to do than to nitpick for nonsense "violations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's an example which I think might show appropriate use of a `delegate`. We have two methods which do some common things but which have different ways of accomplishing a task in the middle of the common work. The `IntConverter<T> delegate` allows them to pass in a way of accomplishing the task which is particular to the calling method.

If it's important to your question (I'm not sure) this example demonstrates requiring an actual `delegate` type (as opposed to a generic `Func<>` type) because the delegate type itself has a generic parameter.

```
private delegate int IntConverter<T>(T value);

public void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    DoCoreStuff(value, v => ConvertToIntInOneWay(v));
}

public void DoSomethingElse<T>(T value)
{
    DoCoreStuff(value, v => ConvertToIntInAnotherWay(v));
}

private void DoCoreStuff<T>(T value, IntConverter<T> intConverter)
{
    // Do a bunch of common stuff
    var intValue = intConverter(value);
    // Do a bunch of other core stuff, probably with the intValue
}
```

The same situation could be solved without a delegate like this:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    DoFirstLotOfCoreStuff(value);
    DoSecondLotOfCoreStuff(ConvertToIntInOneWay(v));
}

public void DoSomethingElse<T>(T value)
{
    DoFirstLotOfCoreStuff(value);
    DoSecondLotOfCoreStuff(ConvertToIntInAnotherWay(v));
}

private void DoFirstLotOfCoreStuff<T>(T value)
{
    // Do a bunch of other core stuff, probably with the intValue
}

private void DoSecondLotOfCoreStuff(int intValue)
{
    // Do a bunch of other core stuff, probably with the intValue
}
```

...but this is a weaker solution because of the [duplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) in `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingElse` and the now-required [Sequential-coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling)-type invoking of the two helper methods.

For fun, here's another way of solving the same problem:

```
public interface IIntConverter<T>
{
    int Convert(T value);
}

public void DoSomething<T>(T value)
{
    DoCoreStuff(value, new ConvertToIntInOneWayIntConverter());
}

public void DoSomethingElse<T>(T value)
{
    DoCoreStuff(value, new ConvertToIntInAnotherWayIntConverter());
}

private void DoCoreStuff<T>(T value, IIntConverter<T> intConverter)
{
    // Do a bunch of common stuff
    var intValue = intConverter.Convert(value);
    // Do a bunch of other core stuff, probably with the intValue
}
```

...this is a weaker solution because we've invented an interface and two implementations when what we wanted to do [was simple enough](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) to do with a delegate.

Comment: You've just described how to use delegates, and when they might come in handy. The OP wants an example of how you would've done it without delegates, proving that you should've done it with delegates, and delegates alone.

Comment: Good point well made, but the example surely demonstrates a situation where doing it without delegates would be a lot more awkward than doing it with delegates. Therefore delegates.

Comment: It does. In my opinion (damn! there we go!). 
So, then, delegates all the way? For all scenario's where other viable alternatives exist?

Comment: Well, no... for the scenarios where the alternatives are "a lot more awkward" :)

Comment: And back to square one: Can you list those scenario's for me, with an example? :)

Comment: The above is an example :) I could include a spurious use of delegates if that's helpful...? :)

Comment: Nononono! The request is for negative proof! Give examples what it would look like if you do NOT use delegates which then proof why you should proof delegates. And make it exhaustive please, and non-debatable or opinion-prone. Basically: Formal proof why One Should Use Delegates.

Comment: To answer my question, you WOULD need to show code sample of same problem solved without delegates.

Comment: In for a penny... I've updated my answer. @Willem - do you require mathematical proof of a particular technique being superior to all its alternatives when you write software? If so I don't know how you get anything done, it not then why are you asking me for it? The wording above implies that "opinion based on expert experience" is acceptable and valuable - formal proofs are not required.

Comment: My question has been satisfied..no higher math required

Comment: BTW @Willem: The measure of quality of code is not subjective.  And anyone who thinks it is, could also argue about the subjectivity of the yield of 2+2.  And I don't care if you do, just don't build any bridges or tall buildings..